# How to add multiple tasks in one command on Taskwarrior?

Tags: command-line, utilities, taskwarrior

How can I add multiple tasks in one command line on [Taskwarrior](https://taskwarrior.org/)?

I'd like to achieve something like:

```
task add task1 tag:tag1, task2 tag:tag2
```

I think there should be a delimiter to separate tasks.

Comment: As a work around, you could do it in a shell loop…

Answer (score 2):

If you literally just need to do this in one line, you could do:

```
task add "Get some foo"; task add "Get some bar"
```

This just uses the `;` token native to the shell.

Comment: thanks for the answer but i wondered if it were possible to.do.so in one process/command; i think implementing such a syntax directly for the command itself (without handing it over to the shell) would be very handy and neat

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you're still interested in this. I created a pretty quick bash shell script that suited my purposes at the time. It asks if you want to set a Project or Tag(s) for the tasks then quickly creates multiple new tasks. Uses some quite loud colour combinations, I think I'd only just discovered the "echo -e " method at the time ;o)

I was searching today and found your post because I wanted to develop the script to do dependencies but it looks like I might have to learn python; I also want to do some google reminder syncing. If you've found a good tool then I'd be glad to know what solution you settled on.

kr
A

---

```
#!/bin/bash

#  Script:  twmulti
#  Created: 2016.02.11
#  Current: ~/Bin

#   clear the variables just in case a recent session set them
PRJNAME=""
TAGNAME=""
TSKNAME=""

clear

echo -e "\e[1;33;41mENTER PROJECT NAME >\e[0;m" 
read PRJNAME
if [ -z $PRJNAME ] ; then PRJNAME="" ; fi

echo -e "\n\e[1;33;41mENTER ANY TAG(S)  >\e[0;m" 
read TEMPTAGNAME
TAGNAME="+"`echo $TEMPTAGNAME | sed 's/ / +/g'`
if [ -z $TEMPTAGNAME ] ; then TAGNAME=""; fi

while :
do
    clear 
    echo -e "\e[1;33;41mENTER TASK DESCRIPTION (Project:$PRJNAME) >\e[0;m"
    echo -e "\e[1;33;41mor enter again to quit\e[0;m"
    read TSKNAME
        if [ -z $TSKNAME ] ; then exit ; fi 
        task add project\:$PRJNAME $TAGNAME $TSKNAME 1>/dev/null
    echo -e "\e[0;m"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Sardathrion pointed out in the comment, this would look like this:

```
for i in "task 1" "task 2" "task 3"; do task add "$i"; done
```

Answer (score 2):

Hoping this might help someone, you can use `task import` for such a usecase.
From `task`'s man page:

```
       task import [<file> ...]
              Imports tasks in the JSON format.  Can be used to add new tasks, or update existing ones.  Tasks are identified by their UUID.

              If no file or "-" is specified, import tasks from STDIN.

              Setting rc.recurrence.confirmation to an appropriate level is recommended if import is to be used in automated workflows.  See taskrc(5).

              For importing other file formats, the standard task release comes with a few example scripts, such as:

                import-todo.sh.pl
                import-yaml.pl
```

So, you can something like this:

```bsh
$ echo '[{"description":"task1"},{"description":"task2"}]' |task import -
Importing 'STDIN'
 add  bfc337ce-b446-453d-8cfe-c570bc1b5f03 task1
 add  556a737c-11f3-4a21-a872-67e56b75cdc4 task2
Imported 2 tasks.
```

Of course you can add any attribute as you wish (tags, project, UDA, etc). The JSON schema is available here: https://taskwarrior.org/docs/design/task.html

To add tasks in bulk you can create a file first with all the information and then just feed it to `task`, or just use Vim with [taskwiki](https://github.com/tools-life/taskwiki) :)